# OpenTelemetry missing packages

Tags: go, open-telemetry, go1.14

I am getting following error in my Go project. I am using `go mod` to manage dependencies. It looks like the latest version of `opentelemetry` doesn't specific packages. But how should I fix them

```
go get ./...                           
go: finding module for package go.opentelemetry.io/otel/internal/opentelemetry-proto-gen/collector/trace/v1
go: finding module for package go.opentelemetry.io/otel/internal/opentelemetry-proto-gen/collector/metrics/v1
go: finding module for package go.opentelemetry.io/otel/api/label
go: finding module for package go.opentelemetry.io/otel/api/standard
go: finding module for package go.opentelemetry.io/otel/instrumentation/othttp
go: finding module for package go.opentelemetry.io/otel/api/kv
go: finding module for package go.opentelemetry.io/otel/internal/opentelemetry-proto-gen/trace/v1
go: finding module for package go.opentelemetry.io/otel/internal/opentelemetry-proto-gen/common/v1
go: finding module for package go.opentelemetry.io/otel/internal/opentelemetry-proto-gen/resource/v1
go: finding module for package go.opentelemetry.io/otel/internal/opentelemetry-proto-gen/metrics/v1
go: finding module for package go.opentelemetry.io/otel/internal/opentelemetry-proto-gen/collector/trace/v1
go: finding module for package go.opentelemetry.io/otel/api/kv
go: finding module for package go.opentelemetry.io/otel/internal/opentelemetry-proto-gen/collector/metrics/v1
go: finding module for package go.opentelemetry.io/otel/api/standard
go: finding module for package go.opentelemetry.io/otel/instrumentation/othttp
go: finding module for package go.opentelemetry.io/otel/api/label
go: finding module for package go.opentelemetry.io/otel/internal/opentelemetry-proto-gen/metrics/v1
go: finding module for package go.opentelemetry.io/otel/internal/opentelemetry-proto-gen/resource/v1
go: finding module for package go.opentelemetry.io/otel/internal/opentelemetry-proto-gen/common/v1
go: finding module for package go.opentelemetry.io/otel/internal/opentelemetry-proto-gen/trace/v1
pkg/tracing/opentelemetry.go:10:2: module go.opentelemetry.io/otel@latest found (v0.13.0), but does not contain package go.opentelemetry.io/otel/api/kv
../go/pkg/mod/go.opentelemetry.io/otel/exporters/otlp@v0.10.0/internal/transform/metric.go:30:2: module go.opentelemetry.io/otel@latest found (v0.13.0), but does not contain package go.opentelemetry.io/otel/api/label
pkg/tracing/opentelemetry.go:12:2: module go.opentelemetry.io/otel@latest found (v0.13.0), but does not contain package go.opentelemetry.io/otel/api/standard
../go/pkg/mod/go.opentelemetry.io/otel/exporters/otlp@v0.10.0/otlp.go:28:2: module go.opentelemetry.io/otel@latest found (v0.13.0), but does not contain package go.opentelemetry.io/otel/internal/opentelemetry-proto-gen/collector/metrics/v1
../go/pkg/mod/go.opentelemetry.io/otel/exporters/otlp@v0.10.0/otlp.go:29:2: module go.opentelemetry.io/otel@latest found (v0.13.0), but does not contain package go.opentelemetry.io/otel/internal/opentelemetry-proto-gen/collector/trace/v1
../go/pkg/mod/go.opentelemetry.io/otel/exporters/otlp@v0.10.0/internal/transform/attribute.go:18:2: module go.opentelemetry.io/otel@latest found (v0.13.0), but does not contain package go.opentelemetry.io/otel/internal/opentelemetry-proto-gen/common/v1
../go/pkg/mod/go.opentelemetry.io/otel/exporters/otlp@v0.10.0/internal/transform/metric.go:27:2: module go.opentelemetry.io/otel@latest found (v0.13.0), but does not contain package go.opentelemetry.io/otel/internal/opentelemetry-proto-gen/metrics/v1
../go/pkg/mod/go.opentelemetry.io/otel/exporters/otlp@v0.10.0/internal/transform/metric.go:28:2: module go.opentelemetry.io/otel@latest found (v0.13.0), but does not contain package go.opentelemetry.io/otel/internal/opentelemetry-proto-gen/resource/v1
../go/pkg/mod/go.opentelemetry.io/otel/exporters/otlp@v0.10.0/internal/transform/span.go:20:2: module go.opentelemetry.io/otel@latest found (v0.13.0), but does not contain package go.opentelemetry.io/otel/internal/opentelemetry-proto-gen/trace/v1
pkg/home/net/http/fw_handlers.go:11:2: module go.opentelemetry.io/otel@latest found (v0.13.0), but does not contain package go.opentelemetry.io/otel/instrumentation/othttp
```

Comment: Figure out which version of opentelemetry you need, and specify that?

Comment: I need `v0.10.0` but couldn't figure out how to get specific. I tried ` go get go.opentelemetry.io/otel@v0.10.0` but still got this error

Comment: `go.opentelemetry.io/otel` is not the only `opentelemetry` module you're using. Make sure you specify module versions for other packages like `go.opentelemetry.io/otel/exporters/otlp`

Answer (score 7):

I also have similar error.

```
go.opentelemetry.io/contrib/instrumentation/net/http/otelhttp imports
go.opentelemetry.io/otel/metric/global: module go.opentelemetry.io/otel/metric@latest found (v1.16.0), but does not contain package go.opentelemetry.io/otel/metric/global

go.opentelemetry.io/contrib/instrumentation/net/http/otelhttp imports
go.opentelemetry.io/otel/metric/instrument: module go.opentelemetry.io/otel/metric@latest found (v1.16.0), but does not contain package go.opentelemetry.io/otel/metric/instrument
```

`go.opentelemetry.io/contrib/instrumentation/net/http/otelhttp v0.40.0` in go.mod

#### my solution

upgrade `go.opentelemetry.io/contrib/instrumentation/net/http/otelhttp`

```
go get go.opentelemetry.io/contrib/instrumentation/net/http/otelhttp@latest
```

problem solved.

The reason is that the child dependency version upgrade needs to upgrade the parent dependency.

Answer (score 5):

I was running into a similar issue and *thoroughly* cleaning the cache did the trick. Again, I believe this removes all the packages from your system so use with caution:

```
go clean -cache -modcache -i -r
```